# Installing matplotlib with pip under macos 11.5

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pip

I’m trying to install matplotlib with pip on an M1 mac with macOS 11.4, but get the following error:

```
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.4.3.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.21.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib) (8.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: matplotlib
  Building wheel for matplotlib (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for matplotlib (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/z1/6807g5fn2tl27vlms0t5wqnm0000gq/T/pip-install-7jtr3een/matplotlib_9167cea08b4b47ea908a69fdb7be92b9/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/z1/6807g5fn2tl27vlms0t5wqnm0000gq/T/pip-install-7jtr3een/matplotlib_9167cea08b4b47ea908a69fdb7be92b9/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/z1/6807g5fn2tl27vlms0t5wqnm0000gq/T/pip-wheel-ipsv3z0z
       cwd: /private/var/folders/z1/6807g5fn2tl27vlms0t5wqnm0000gq/T/pip-install-7jtr3een/matplotlib_9167cea08b4b47ea908a69fdb7be92b9/
  Complete output (639 lines):
```

(due to lengh restrictions here, the full output can be found at https://pastebin.com/MyGhbE5q )

Any ideas how to fix?

This happens both if I run

```
pip install matplotlib
```

or

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

Comment: did you read the discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621?

Comment: @It_is_Chris Yes, it says "If you have been directed here from a pip warning, you don't need to take any action at this stage. Nothing is currently expected to break until Python 3.12, and a full solution will be implemented well before then." I'm following this advise and did not do anything.

Comment: Can you post the config.log?

Comment: @idonthaveaname Where can I find this? It is neither in my current working directory, nor my home folder or in ~/.config . And the temporary folder mentioned in the error messages seems to not exist.

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you can specify the log file using pip install matplotlib --log *insert your file path here*

Comment: @idonthaveaname Thanks! I did not know about the --log option! I put the log file here: https://textbin.net/raw/r0ent4bnwc